# How to save a python docxTemplate as pdf quickly

Tags: python, performance, templates, pdf, docx

At the moment I use a script to populate a template for each of the entries in our database and generate a docx file for each entry. Following that I convert that docx file to a pdf and mail it to the user.

For this I use following code :

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docx2pdf import convert

pathToTemplate='template.docx'
outputPath='output.docx'

template = DocxTemplate(pathToTemplate)
context = person.get_context(short) # gets the context used to render the document
template.render(context)
template.save(outputPath)
pdfpath = outputPath[:-4]+'pdf'
convert(outputPath, pdfpath)
```

This part of the code is embedded in a loop and when measuring the time needed to generate the context from the database (in the `person.get_context(short)` function) and generating the docx file it gives me a result between 0.5s - 1.0s. When measuring the time needed to convert this docx to pdf it gives me a time of 5.0s - 7.0s.

Because the loop has to loop over > 1000 users, this is the difference can add up. Does anyone have an idea how the DocxTemplate kan save to pdf directly (and how fast this is) or if there is a faster way to generate the pdf files?

Comment: I tried to give a .pdf extension to the outputPath. The script runs, but the filetype still is a docx and opening it gives an extension error. Can't find anything in the documentation of docxtpl about the DocxTemplate.save function.

Comment: Why not run a simple hello world example and see what you get. This should either tell you it's something in the document or that there is nothing you can do with the code to speed it ip.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know you just can't do it with the docx library itself, but I have found an alternate way to achieve this, we can convert the docx to pdf using the following code

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
import time
import os

from win32com import client
word_app = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

for i , j in df.iterrows():
    Name = j["Party_Name"]

    tpl = DocxTemplate("Invoice_Template.docx")
    dicty = df.to_dict()
    x = df.to_dict(orient="records")
    context = x
    tpl.render(context[i])
    tpl.save("hello.docx")


    rod = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print(rod)
    time.sleep(2)
    #converting to pdf 
    doc = word_app.Documents.Open(rod + "\\1.docx")
    doc.SaveAs(rod + "\\hello.pdf", FileFormat=17)
```